# Не могу запустить свое SpringMVC приложение на Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

Я изучаю *Spring MVC*. Использую *Tomcat 8*, *IntelliJ IDEA 15*, *Maven 3*.

Проблема: деплой проходит — 404 при попытке перейти `localhost:8080/greeting`.

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Spring-MVC</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>ua.andrewiscom.springtest.config</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

greeting.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, ${name}!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloController.java

```
package ua.andrewiscom.springtest.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

MvcConfig.java

```
package ua.andrewiscom.springtest.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="ua.andrewiscom")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

В общем мне очень не нравится конфигурировать через *XML*. Нашел кое-как туториал по "конфигурации средствами Java" и собственно сделал её в `MvcConfig`. Скопипастил и переделал под себя. Потом попытался сделать [Hello world](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) обычный. Логи говорят, что деплой *war*-архива проходит.

Comment: Вообще то непонятно, что вы там делаете и что собираете. Прежде чем деплоить, напишите, какую ошибку выдает test. С права в IDEA кликните на Maven Project, затем кликните на test и напишите ошибку.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Извините, может я чего то недопонимаю, но кажись вы меня просто валите. Или я ошибаюсь? :)

Answer (score 1):

В маппинге dispatcherServlet после слэша надо поставить * : `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Дальше:
если есть `context-param`, зачем тот же самы параметр указывать в `init-param`

Ну и комментарии:

> В общем мне очень не нравится конфигурировать через XML.

Разберитесь в чем плюсы и минусы разных способов конфигурирования.

> Нашел кое-как туториал по "конфигурации средствами Java" и собственно сделал её в MvcConfig.

В Spring нет ничего лучше их родного [референса](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) - там все максимально лаконично и понятно.

> Скопипастил и переделал под себя.

Даже, если вы делаете по туториалу, то нужно разобрать каждую строчку кода, понять что и как происходит, и зачем это написано так, а не иначе.

К слову о логах, если бы вы посмотрели в логи, то могли бы заметить, что spring выдает warning на невалидный URL

Answer (score 1):

Различаются два контекста - Root WebApplicationContext и второй контекст сервлета. По правильному я бы на вашем месте указал в конфиге так:

```
<!-- Bootstrap the root context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- @Configuration classes or package -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>ua.andrewiscom.springtest.config</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

На Хабре есть прекрасные две статьи про инициализацию контекста, советую с ними ознакомиться.
[Ссылка 1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/222579/)
[Ссылка 2](http://habrahabr.ru/company/jugru/blog/218203/)

Answer (score 0):

Скачай Tomcat 9 версии. У меня была такая же проблема, когда я пытался завести сервер на 8 и 10 версии.